# Set-up Apple Passkey for private users

Tags: apple, webauthn

The demos I've seen for Passkey assume that any public user can register with a website. What about the situation where you want to set up a passkey for an admin user of a website? i.e. How does an admin create a new Passkey on their device and send the public key to an administrator to add to their account?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an open registration system, the existing admin could simply change the role of "Ian Warburton" from "normal user" to "admin".

If the user was not registered at all previously, the admin could provide an email, and a registration link could be sent to ianwarburton@invalid-email.com

Comment: How do you verify that the person using the registration link is who they say they are?

Comment: @IanWarburton you may assume their email is not wiretapped, so the unique link you provided is not used by anyone else. You could have them confirm offline that they signed up with certain username. You could have them sign up in the same room where you are...